# Keyboard shows and will not dismiss

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uiviewanimation, first-responder

I have a view with multiple UITextfields, when I quickly tap and type within the UITextFields randomly, after a while I enter a state in which the keyboard is showing but will not dismiss. Pressing the bottom right "Dismiss Keyboard" button does not work. All keys on the keyboard still make a clicking noise and turn grey when pressed.

In the root view controller I observe all keyboard hide and show events.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(keyboardDidShowWithNotification:) 
name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(keyboardDidHideWithNotification:) 
name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyboardDidShowWithNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    DataViewController* theCurrentController = (DataViewController*)self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
    float yCoord;
    UITextField* text = (UITextField*)[self findFirstResponder:theCurrentController.view];
    if(text.frame.origin.y < 10)
         yCoord = text.superview.frame.origin.y;
    else
         yCoord = text.frame.origin.y;

    NSLog(@"%f",yCoord);
    if(yCoord > 410)
        offCenter = 230;
    else if (yCoord > 240)
        offCenter = 150;

    if(offCenter > 0)
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
delay:0                           options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         CGPoint adjust = CGPointMake(0, -1*offCenter);
                         CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.pageViewController.view.center.x+adjust.x, self.pageViewController.view.center.y+adjust.y);
                         [self.pageViewController.view setCenter:newCenter];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

}


- (void)keyboardDidHideWithNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if(offCenter)
    {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3  delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         CGPoint adjust = CGPointMake(0, offCenter);

                         CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.pageViewController.view.center.x+adjust.x, self.pageViewController.view.center.y+adjust.y);
                         [self.pageViewController.view setCenter:newCenter];

                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
offCenter = 0;
}
```

When the keyboard shows, if the firstresponder is hidden by the keyboard I animate the view up so the user can see the UITextField. When the keyboard hides, if the view is positioned high it returns to centre.

In the ViewController itself implement a UITapGestureRecognizer

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.heartRateTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.systolicBPTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.diastolicBPTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

when a tap occurs I resignFirstResponder on all the UITextFields.

The ViewController is also a UITextFieldDelegate that implement the following

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES; 
}

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)textEntered {
    if(([textEntered intValue] && textField.text.length < 3) || [textEntered  isEqualToString:@""] || ([textEntered isEqualToString:@"0"] && textField.text.length > 0 && textField.text.length < 3))
    return YES;
        else
    return NO;
}
```

Breakpoints in these two event handles do not trigger even though return button and all other keys on the keyboard is still active. I am able to tap them and they clock and turn grey.

All of these work when the view is not in this error state. Only after randomly tapping and typing does the view stop responding and none of these events are triggered. This error state only occurs on pages that have UITextField hidden by the keyboard and require an animation. This error state only occurs while the view is centred, never while high. This error state only occurs when tapping between UITextFields that are below the keyboard hidden line and above the keyboard hidden line.

To escape the error state you simply tap on a UITextField that is visible. The UITextField becomes the first responder and now all events work as normal.

Any ideas as to why this is happening or how to debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks problematic to me:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                              initWithTarget:self
                              action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
```

You should try making the target `self.view` instead:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                              initWithTarget:self.view
                              action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
```

If that doesn't fix it, I would create a blank `UIButton` that sits below all other UI elements on the view controller, and assign the `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s target to that button.